# No bars appear for geom_bar

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

I am trying to get a bar chart with parties' EU score on x and the percentage of votes each party got on y. The variable Vote_survey is already aggregated power votes. Here is my code:

```
ExpertSurvey=read_excel("Expert Survey.xlsx")
ggplot(ExpertSurvey)+
  geom_bar(aes(x=ExpertSurvey$"EU_score", y=ExpertSurvey$"Vote_survey"), stat = "identity")
```

For some reason, I am getting a a plot with no bars... Where could I be making a mistake here?

Comment: try aes(x=EU_score,y=Vote_survey)

Comment: When asking for help, you should include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: @StupidWolf I think the OP may benefit from an explanation why you have suggested this:) Sofiya - this was suggested because one does not need and actually should not use `$` within the `aes` call.

Comment: Hi Sofiya, I actually simulated data and your code, and it should still work. Can you provide an example of the file? I think it's something weird about your data frame ExpertSurvey. Thanks @Tjebo for explaining why the $ inside aes is not needed and sorry I missed out on explaining.